# Uniformly (but not random) spaced set of n-points on an annulus

Tags: delphi, computational-geometry

Good day,

I am currently facing a challenge at work which is becoming quite a pain to solve.

**The Challenge:**

I need to create CAD drawing of a hole pattern for a perforated annular plate which will be laser cut. The holes needs to be as close to equidistant as possible, allowing for even airflow distribution. Total area of the holes needs to equate to 40% of the total annular area. From my calculations I will need 10,190 holes of 6.35mm to accomplish this...

**The Solution:**

Write a small program to calculate the point set's XY coordinates which I can import into my CAD software.

**The Question:**

For this purpose I want to use a *[Fermat's Spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_spiral)* approach to calculate the point coordinates. As a starting point, I used info from *[Marmakoide's Blog](http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1)*. So far I have the point distribution done evenly and looks to be approximately equidistantly spaced. My problem is that I need to, somehow, specify the inner and outer radii of the annulus wherein the point set of N-points must fall. Please not that I am not at all mathematically inclined, so please keep the answers as clear as possible.

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnCalcClick(Sender: TObject);
var golden_angle, radI, radO, rad, theta, x, y : Double;
    i, k, holeQTY, index : integer;
    xCoords, yCoords : Array of Double;
begin
 holeQTY := StrToInt(edtNumHoles.Text);
 golden_angle := Pi * (3 - Sqrt(5));
 radI := StrToFloat(edtRadInner.Text);
 radO := StrToFloat(edtRadOuter.Text);
 SetLength(xCoords, holeQTY);
 SetLength(yCoords, holeQTY);
 for i := 0 to holeQTY - 1 do
   begin
     theta := i * golden_angle;
     rad := Sqrt(i) / Sqrt(holeQTY);
     x := rad * Cos(theta);
     y := rad * Sin(theta);
     xCoords[i] := x;
     yCoords[i] := y;
     StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := IntToStr(i+1) + ' of ' + IntToStr(holeQTY);
     StatusBar1.Update;
     Application.ProcessMessages;
   end;

for k := 0 to holeQTY - 1 do
  begin
    Chart1.Series[0].AddXY(xCoords[k], yCoords[k], '', clBlack);
  end;

end;
```

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Comment: "The holes needs to be as close to equidistant as possible" - so just make triangles, rectangular or better hexagonal (like honeys bee cells) mesh - why you even need the spiral? Wikipedia page clearly shows spiral lines go closer and closer and yet closer to each other as you go away from the centre. Just do a regular planar mesh.

Comment: On the Wikipedia page, it shows 3 florets, with the middle one being the desired outcome. That being the reason for my use of the golden ratio. On [this](http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=1) page you can see the desired effect clearly in the first image.

Comment: so you set to have n = `10,190` and Wiki describes Vogel's method as `r = c * sqrt{n}`. You know the radius of your plate, you know the n you chosen, so you can calculate the "c" coefficient in one expression. Then you start the loop `for n := 0 to 10190-` or maybe `for n := 1 to 10190` and keep calculating radius-angle pairs just like Wikipedia quotes those two Vogel's formulas: `r[n] = c *sqrt{n}, angle[n] = n * 137.508 * degrees-to-radians-coefficient`.

Comment: Do you know the maths you need? If so, what is it? And why can't you code it? And if you need help with maths this is the wrong site.

Comment: It's also a huge mistake to mix your GUI code with your math code, and that ProcessMessages...why?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think  he mixes GUI with maths because that is his demo-research-hacktogether project, not the final result which he would re-implement with separation of responsibilities in mind.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, as Arioch 'The stated, this is not the final version. The GUI code is merely there to visualize the outcome and help with troubleshooting. Also, this code will only be used once, as this project is a once off.

Comment: It's harder to develop it this way. Good separation will make it easier. What about my other point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Normalization taken into account

Given in the `Spreading points` page approach is used to fill the **unit** circle.
You have to add multiplication coefficient A

```
rad := A * Sqrt(i) / Sqrt(N);
```

Last hole with index N should be inside radO:

```
A * Sqrt(N) / Sqrt(N) < radO - HoleRadius
so
A  =  radO - HoleRadius;
```

Now for the first hole:

```
A * Sqrt(N - holeQTY + 1) / Sqrt(N) > (radI + HoleRadius)
N - holeQTY + 1 > N * Sqr((radI + HoleRadius) / A)
N * (1 - Sqr((radI + HoleRadius) / A)) > holeQTY - 1
N = Ceil((holeQTY - 1) / (1 - Sqr((radI + HoleRadius) / A))
```

Result:
You have to draw `holeQTY` points with indexes `(N - holeQTY + 1)..N` using coefficient A. Sample code:

```
var
  A, golden_angle, radI, radO, rad, theta, MinGap: Double;
  N, x, y, i, holeQTY, holeRadius: Integer;
begin
  holeQTY := 120;
  radI := 50;
  radO := 200;
  holeRadius := 4;
  MinGap := 3;
  golden_angle := Pi * (3 - Sqrt(5));
  A := Floor(radO - (holeRadius + MinGap));
  N := Ceil((holeQTY - 1) / (1 - Sqr((radI + holeRadius + MinGap) / A)));
  Canvas.Ellipse(300 - 200, 300 - 200, 300 + 201, 300 + 201);
  Canvas.Ellipse(300 - 50, 300 - 50, 300 + 51, 300 + 51);
  for i := (N - holeQTY + 1) to N do begin
    theta := i * golden_angle;
    rad := A * Sqrt(i) / Sqrt(N);
    x := 300 + Round(rad * Cos(theta));
    y := 300 + Round(rad * Sin(theta));
    Canvas.Ellipse(x - holeRadius, y - holeRadius, x + holeRadius + 1, y + holeRadius + 1);
  end;
```

(picture made before MinGap introduction)

[image]

Code with double values

```
 holeQTY := 17;
  radI := 0.1234;
  radO := 0.23456;
  holeRadius := 0.00635;
  MinGap :=     0.0000635;
  golden_angle := Pi * (3 - Sqrt(5));
  A := radO - (holeRadius + MinGap);
  N := Ceil((holeQTY - 1) / (1 - Sqr((radI + holeRadius + MinGap) / A)));
  for i := (N - holeQTY + 1) to N do begin
    theta := i * golden_angle;
    rad := A * Sqrt(i) / Sqrt(N);
    x := rad * Cos(theta);
    y := rad * Sin(theta);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('r:%5.4f  x:%f y:%f', [rad, x, y]));
  end;
```

produces output

```
r:0.1317  x:0.12 y:0.05
r:0.1397  x:-0.13 y:0.05
r:0.1473  x:0.06 y:-0.13
r:0.1545  x:0.05 y:0.15
r:0.1613  x:-0.14 y:-0.08
r:0.1679  x:0.16 y:-0.04
r:0.1742  x:-0.10 y:0.14
r:0.1804  x:-0.02 y:-0.18
r:0.1863  x:0.14 y:0.12
r:0.1920  x:-0.19 y:0.01
r:0.1976  x:0.14 y:-0.14
r:0.2030  x:-0.01 y:0.20
r:0.2083  x:-0.13 y:-0.16
r:0.2134  x:0.21 y:0.03
r:0.2184  x:-0.18 y:0.12
r:0.2233  x:0.05 y:-0.22
r:0.2281  x:0.11 y:0.20
```

And finally possible function separated from GUI

```
type
  TPointDouble = record
    X, Y: Double;
  end;

function CalcRingPoints(const
                        InnerRadius,
                        OuterRadius,
                        HoleRadius,
                        CoverageRatio //range 0..1
                        : Double)
                        : TArray<TPointDouble>;
//doesn't check input validity and possible hole overlaps!
var
  ACoeff, golden_angle, rad, theta, MinGap, Area: Double;
  N, i, j, holeQTY: Integer;
begin
  holeQTY := Round(CoverageRatio * (Sqr(OuterRadius) - Sqr(InnerRadius)) /
    Sqr(HoleRadius));
  MinGap := 0.1 * HoleRadius;
  golden_angle := Pi * (3 - Sqrt(5));
  ACoeff := OuterRadius - (HoleRadius + MinGap);
  N := Ceil((holeQTY - 1) / (1 - Sqr((InnerRadius + HoleRadius + MinGap) /
    ACoeff)));
  SetLength(Result, holeQTY);

  for i := (N - holeQTY + 1) to N do begin
    theta := i * golden_angle;
    rad := ACoeff * Sqrt(i / N);
    j := i - (N - holeQTY + 1);
    Result[j].X := rad * Cos(theta);
    Result[j].Y := rad * Sin(theta);
  end;
end;
```

and it's usage

```
var
  Pts: TArray<TPointDouble>;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Pts := CalcRingPoints(1, 2, 0.2, 0.5);
  for i := 0 to High(Pts) do
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('%d  r:%5.4f  x:%f y:%f',
      [i, Hypot(Pts[i].X, Pts[i].Y), Pts[i].X, Pts[i].Y]));   
   //37 points
```

Comment: I think he wants to keep increasing point-to-point gap as he traverses the spiral further and further from the centre. However he also wants to be sure that when he covers 180-degree his new holes would not be close to the holes set for the previous turn branch. Since the distance between the Fermat spiral branches goes infinitesimally small after each new turn - and his holes have fixed non-infinitesimal size - I do not think that is even possible.

Comment: @Arioch 'The  I don't see clear question yet ;-) And I agree that Fermat's spiral is rather strange choice. I'd use trigonal grid

Comment: I believe you need one more variable to add - the minimal gap between the hole edge and the edges of inner/outer circles. That that is set to be 10% of hole radius in my answer - just for mere simplicity.

Comment: @Arioch 'The  Thanks, that would improve the look

Comment: I wonder if you can just make the picture on Wolfram Alpha to avoid running Delphi projects

Comment: Alright, I implemented MBo's approach, but changed some of the variables back to Doubles. It works with the radii and holeQTY as in the sample, but breaks down when I use the dimensions and hole qty's I need.

Comment: What are values that cause problems?

Comment: For clarification, the following variables needs to be of type Double: holeRadius, X and Y. Reason being that that's the dimensions required.

Comment: I've used integers for simpler control graphical output. Changing of Integers do doubles should not influence on math here.

Comment: Ok, the issue was with the plotting in the Graph, that is sorted now. But when I tried to run the required dimensions, it breaks. Will have to dig into the reason.

Comment: Floor is not needed for A calculation (my mistake)

Comment: Sorry, but on my side, with your last inputs, I get an invalid floating point operation. It breaks on the first run when calculating the "rad" variable inside the loop.

Comment: ok, my issue was with the minGap which was not set. Could you perhaps try the following on your side? radi=50, radO=200, holeQTY = 350. When I try that, it either breaks, or does not map the points correctly.

Comment: This is real code and it's output. What is N value before the cycle?

Comment: Code works well with `radi=50, radO=200, holeQTY = 350,  HoleRadius := 4.0;
  MinGap := 1.0;`

Comment: N is 394 before the cycle

Comment: N=380 for given above HoleRadius, MinGap. Seems your code is different.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll change my code and try again. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Please add link to `Marmakoide's Blog` to the post body, because it is important for understanding what you wanted.

Comment: Done. Funny thing is, that post on Marmakoide's Blog was the first useful info I got during my searches, but saw that comments where closed on the post, so I decided to post here instead. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see.

The formula for a solid disk is obvious, right?

`r[max] = r_coeff * sqrt(max)` which gives us `r_coeff = r[max]/sqrt[max]`;

Your problem seems to be about what to do when our plane is not the solid disk but a subtraction of a smaller disk from the larger one.

Well, the dumb lazy approach would be to correct the numbers of holes. Since the square of a disk is proportional to the radius squared, and since we want our holes by dispersed mostly equidistant we can hope that as we have many enough holes the share (percentage) of the holes is proportional to the disc square, right ?

So we have

- `N = 10 190 = N_outer_disk - N_inner_disk`
- `N_outer_disk / N_inner_disk ≈ S_outer / S_inner = (R_outer / R_inner)^2`
- `N_inner_disk / N_outer_disk ≈ S_inner / S_outer = (R_inner / R_outer)^2`

And we have to run the loop `I := N_inner_disk + 1 to N_outer_disk` calculating

- `r[I] = r_coeff * SqRt(I)`
- `angle[I] = I * 137.508 * degrees-to-radians-coefficient`

Or perhaps we better run the loop from `N_inner_disk - 10% to N_outer_disk + 10%` and just filter all the exceedingly large output by `(hole_radius + 10%) + r_hole[I] < R_outer` and `r_hole[I] > R_inner + (hole_radius + 10%)` - since our calculations are approximate we would anyway have to employ the filtering, and then we can just use it from starters.

*I believe you need one more variable to add - the minimal gap between the hole edge and the edges of inner/outer circles, so that hoels would not be "drlled" on the edge partially out of the plat. That gap for the lack of said variable and for mere simplicity I set above to be 10% of the hole radius, which is not exactly correct*

Coming back to our N-s...

`N = 10 190 ≈ N_outer_disk - N_outer_disk*(R_inner / R_outer)^2 = N_outer_disk * (1 - (R_inner / R_outer)^2)`

and

`N = 10 190 ≈ N_inner_disk*(R_outer / R_inner)^2 - N_inner_disk = N_inner_disk * ((R_outer / R_inner)^2 - 1)`

Thus for given values of N, R_outer, R_inner

- `N_inner_disk ≈ N / ((R_outer / R_inner)^2 - 1)`
- `N_outer_disk ≈ N / (1 - (R_inner / R_outer)^2)`

Now run your loop from `N_inner+1` to `N_outer`, check the total amount of holes passed through the geometrical filter aforementioned and their accumulated square, and if needed adjust the coefficients slightly to come to slightly better `N_inner` and `N_outer` until you would approach the distribution good enough to suit you.

Consequently the `r_coeff = r[max]/sqrt[max]` would turn into `r_coeff ≈ R_inner/sqrt[N_inner] ≈ R_outer/sqrt[N_outer]`
Checking that the coefficients calculated with those two methods are very close to each other would be another check that the calculations of two N-s themselves were internally consistent.